# Getting xaml class name(reference) through its child ui control

Tags: c#, class, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there any way to access xaml class reference/name through its child ui control ?
the code is--->

```
private void AvailableItemListScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             _listScrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;

             Binding binding = new Binding();
             binding.Source = _listScrollViewer;
             binding.Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset");
             binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
             this.SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding); <---//(this)
        }
```

Where this (shown above) referring the parent class which contains `_listScrollViewer` control, but I want to write `AvailableItemListScrollViewer_Loaded` method for all the pages of my app, so I am putting it into a separate class, but here this listener only receiving that ui element reference, so how can i get the parent class ? So I can write the last line of code above something like this--->

```
(class reference).SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use XAML binding here ? Smth like

```
<Page ListVerticalOffset="{Binding Path="VerticalOffset" 
                                   ElementName="ScrollViewerName"}/>
```

Simply copy this binding to every page you need with according ElementName